# Typesetting formula beside explanation of variables

Tags: math-mode, spacing, macros

I've been using the below snippet for quite a while now to typeset important formulas in my documents. Until now I always copy-pasted the snippet and manually tweaked it until the spacing looked satisfying, but thats not why we're using LaTeX, right?

I'd love my snippet to **even out spacings automatically** (speaking the three marked spaces in the screenshot below should be the same size). Also some kind of macro that gives it a **nicer input format** with less redundant copy-pasting would be very nice (e.g. not having to type `\vspace{\baselineskip}`, `\begingroup` etc. every time). How can I achieve that? (I guess there are a lot more possibilities to polish it up so of course I'm open to other suggestions as well.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\vspace{\baselineskip}
\begingroup
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{crl}
\multirow{4}{.3\textwidth}{%
\centering
$Re = \dfrac{v\cdot d}{\nu}$
}
&$Re$&\dots Reynolds number $[-]$\\
&$v$&\dots velocity of the fluid $[\si{\milli\meter\per\second}]$\\
&$d$&\dots characteristic linear dimension $[\si{\milli\meter}]$\\
&$\nu$&\dots kinematic viscosity $[\si{\milli\meter\squared\per\second}]$
\end{tabular}
\endgroup
\vspace{\baselineskip}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image: Example screenshot]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit** Adding equation numbers and looking after `\si{...}`

The code below defines a command `\ExplainedFormula` that when given

```
\ExplainedFormula{\Re = \dfrac{v\cdot d}{\nu}}
     {\Re: Reynolds number:,
        v: velocity of the fluid: \milli\meter\per\second,
        d: characteristic linear dimension: \milli\meter,
      \nu: kinematic viscosity: \milli\meter\squared\per\second
     }
Nulla malesuada porttitor diam. Donec felis erat, congue non,
volutpat at, tincidunt tristique, libero. Vivamus viverra fermentum
felis. Donec nonummy pellentesque ante.
\ExplainedFormula*{\Re = \dfrac{v\cdot d}{\nu}}
     {\Re: Reynolds number:,
        v: velocity of the fluid: \milli\meter\per\second,
        d: characteristic linear dimension: \milli\meter,
      \nu: kinematic viscosity: \milli\meter\squared\per\second
     }
```

will produce output like this:

[image]

By default, `\ExplainedFormula` will add an equation number and there is a starred version, `\ExplainedFormula*`, that omits the equation number. The equation number is on the left, because this is where I always put it:) To put it on the right move the line `\IfBooleanF{#1}{\refstepcounter{equation}\rlap{(\theequation)}}` so that it is after the last `\hfil` in `\ExplainedFormula` and change the `\rlap` to `\llap`...perhaps I should do this automatically...
`

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse}

\renewcommand\Re{\mathop{\textrm{Re}}}
\def\Explain#1:#2:#3!!!{% \Explain variable : description : unit !!!
  $#1$ & #2 $[\if\relax\detokenize{#3}\relax-\else\si{#3}\fi]$
  \\
}% add a line of explanation
\NewDocumentCommand\ExplainedFormula{ s m m }{% 
% usage: \ExplainedFormula{formula}{csv explanation}
  \begin{center}
  \hbox to\textwidth{%
        \IfBooleanF{#1}{\refstepcounter{equation}\rlap{(\theequation)}}
        \hfil$\displaystyle#2$
        \hfil\renewcommand*\do[1]{\Explain##1!!!}%
          \begin{tabular}{r@{\dots}l}\docsvlist{#3}\end{tabular}
        \hfil%
  }%
  \end{center}
}

\begin{document}

\ExplainedFormula{\Re = \dfrac{v\cdot d}{\nu}}
     {\Re: Reynolds number:,
        v: velocity of the fluid: \milli\meter\per\second,
        d: characteristic linear dimension: \milli\meter,
      \nu: kinematic viscosity: \milli\meter\squared\per\second
     }
Nulla malesuada porttitor diam. Donec felis erat, congue non,
volutpat at, tincidunt tristique, libero. Vivamus viverra fermentum
felis. Donec nonummy pellentesque ante.
\ExplainedFormula*{\Re = \dfrac{v\cdot d}{\nu}}
     {\Re: Reynolds number:,
        v: velocity of the fluid: \milli\meter\per\second,
        d: characteristic linear dimension: \milli\meter,
      \nu: kinematic viscosity: \milli\meter\squared\per\second
     }

\end{document}
```

Some words of explanation:

- The `\ExplainedFormula` macro is defined using `\NewDocumentCommand` from the [xparse](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse) package. The `s m m` specification says that `\ExplainedFormula` has three arguments, an optional `*` and two mandatory arguments. The equation number is not printed if the `*` is present.
- The mandatory arguments of `\ExplainedFormula` are for the formula and a *comma separated list* of "explanations". In turn, each "explanation" consists of a variable followed by `:` followed by the explanation followed by another `:` and then the `\si` unit, which should be left blank if there is none (such as for the Reynolds number in the example above. The explanations should not contain `!!!` as this is used by `\Explain` to separate the formula and description components. The parts of the formulas should not be surrounded by `$...$` as these are added by `\ExplainedFormula`
- The comma separated list of explanations is processed using `\docsvlist` from the [etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package together with some trickery (via `\Explain`), to separate the formula component and the description. What happens is that `\do` gets given each part of the comma separated descriptions, such as `\Re: Reynolds number:`, and it gives this to `\Explain` with  `!!!` added on  the end so that the `\Explain` macro knows where `#3` ends.
- Everything is thrown inside an `\hbox` of width `\textwidth` and the components of the box are separated by `\hfil`'s, each of which will expand equally to fill up the available space. This should give the required equidistant spacing
- I have replaced `Re` by `\Re`, which is given by `\renewcommand\Re{\mathop{\textrm{Re}}}`
- I don't really like the `\dots` in the explanation. I would probably add space either side, using something like `@{\,\dots\,}` in the tabular definition, or instead use a colon or equals sign...

Comment: +1 for the consideration of equation numbers. Wouldn't `\mathop{\textrm{Re}}` result in incorrect spacing? I'd use just `\textrm{Re}` as the definition of `\Re`. Also I think in the first point of your explanations you used the wrong seperator (in your code you use `:` but in the explanation `/`).

Comment: `\Re` is no operator. It has nothing to do with real and imaginary part but is a dimensionless value. And I just meant, that I didn't waste a single thought on the equation numbers.

Comment: @Skillmon Certain "important" variables I like TeX to treat as operators in equations so that they are displayed more prominently. I never use the Reynold's number but if I did then I would probably define it this way.

Comment: Wow, nice input format, love it! I tried to do a minor addition myself but found that I don't understand the code well enough to get it to work (especially I don't get the exact effect of the`!!!`). What I'd like to add is the automatic addition of `$[\si{` before and `}]$` after the unit part. I imagine this might be easy with the use of a second separator between explanation and unit like the already used `:`? Could you help me you with that? If you have a nice idea for including equation numbers, that would be really useful as well.

Comment: @MaxD I have added equations and taken care of the `\si` units. In addition, there are a few more words of explanation.

Comment: Awesome, and you even included a special case for unitless numbers. I intended to solve this with a custom-defined unit like `\nounit` in the `siunitx` package but this works quite as well. Accept!

Comment: @MaxD I had to cater for this because it was part of your MWE:)

Answer (score 5):

I eliminate the `multirow` and `tabular`s altogether.  I use `\hfill` to achieve equal spacing, a TABstack for the explanation, and a `\vcenter`ed `\hbox` for the formula. Don't forget the `\noindent`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\vspace{\baselineskip}%
\noindent\hfill%
$\vcenter{\hbox{$Re = \dfrac{v\cdot d}{\nu}$}}$%
\hfill%
\alignCenterstack{%
$Re$&\dots Reynolds number $[-]$\\
$v$&\dots velocity of the fluid $[\si{\milli\meter\per\second}]$\\
$d$&\dots characteristic linear dimension $[\si{\milli\meter}]$\\
$\nu$&\dots kinematic viscosity $[\si{\milli\meter\squared\per\second}]$
}%
\hfill%
\vspace{\baselineskip}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Easy to place in a macro, here as `\explainedFormula`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\newcommand\explainedFormula[2]{%
  \vspace{\baselineskip}%
  \noindent\hfill%
  $\vcenter{\hbox{$#1$}}$\hfill%
  \alignCenterstack{#2}\hfill%
  \vspace{\baselineskip}
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\explainedFormula{Re = \dfrac{v\cdot d}{\nu}}
{%
$Re$&\dots Reynolds number $[-]$\\
$v$&\dots velocity of the fluid $[\si{\milli\meter\per\second}]$\\
$d$&\dots characteristic linear dimension $[\si{\milli\meter}]$\\
$\nu$&\dots kinematic viscosity $[\si{\milli\meter\squared\per\second}]$
}%

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple not very versatile implementation. The environment *must* contain the command `\description` (which is not executed as a command).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{environ,pbox}

\NewEnviron{MaxD}{%
  \expandafter\parseMaxD\BODY\endparseMaxD%
}

\long\def\parseMaxD#1\description#2\endparseMaxD{
  \vspace{\baselineskip}%
  \hfill%
  \pbox{0.45\linewidth}{$#1$}%
  \hfill%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}r@{\dots}l@{}}%
    #2%
  \end{tabular}%
  \hfill%
  \vspace{\baselineskip}}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\vspace{\baselineskip}
\begingroup
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{crl}
\multirow{4}{.3\textwidth}{%
\centering
$Re = \dfrac{v\cdot d}{\nu}$
}
&$Re$&\dots Reynolds number $[-]$\\
&$v$&\dots velocity of the fluid $[\si{\milli\meter\per\second}]$\\
&$d$&\dots characteristic linear dimension $[\si{\milli\meter}]$\\
&$\nu$&\dots kinematic viscosity $[\si{\milli\meter\squared\per\second}]$
\end{tabular}
\endgroup
\vspace{\baselineskip}


\begin{MaxD}
  Re = \dfrac{v\cdot d}{\nu}
  \description
  $Re$& Reynolds number $[-]$\\
  $v$& velocity of the fluid $[\si{\milli\meter\per\second}]$\\
  $d$& characteristic linear dimension $[\si{\milli\meter}]$\\
  $\nu$& kinematic viscosity $[\si{\milli\meter\squared\per\second}]$
\end{MaxD}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

To make it at least a bit more versatile, you could use the `tabularx` package and use the following as definition of `\parseMaxD` instead:

```
\usepackage{tabularx}
\long\def\parseMaxD#1\description#2\endparseMaxD{
  \vspace{\baselineskip}%
  \hfill%
  \pbox{0.45\linewidth}{$#1$}%
  \hfill%
  \begin{tabularx}{0.5\linewidth}{@{}r@{\dots}X@{}}%
    #2%
  \end{tabularx}%
  \hfill%
  \vspace{\baselineskip}}
```

You could as well always typeset the formula in `\displaystyle` using `\pbox{0.45\linewidth}{$\displaystyle #1$}`.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite simple; but note `\Ren` for the Reynolds number (using `Re` in math mode will add unwanted space between the letters).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\Ren}{\mathit{Re}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1]
\begin{equation}
\Ren = \frac{vd}{\nu}
\qquad
\begin{aligned}
\Ren &\dots\text{Reynolds number (--)}\\
v    &\dots\text{velocity of the fluid (\si{\milli\meter\per\second})}\\
d    &\dots\text{characteristic linear dimension (\si{\milli\meter})}\\
\nu  &\dots\text{kinematic viscosity (\si{\milli\meter\squared\per\second})}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, with reduced vertical spacing and perhaps easier input:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\Ren}{\mathit{Re}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1]
\begin{equation}
\Ren = \frac{vd}{\nu}
\qquad
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{$}r<{$}@{$\dots$}l@{}}
\Ren & Reynolds number (--)\\
v    & velocity of the fluid (\si{\milli\meter\per\second})\\
d    & characteristic linear dimension (\si{\milli\meter})\\
\nu  & kinematic viscosity (\si{\milli\meter\squared\per\second})
\end{tabular}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you prefer a single environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\Ren}{\mathit{Re}}
\newenvironment{formulaexplained}
 {\qquad\begin{tabular}{@{}>{$}r<{$}@{$\dots$}l@{}}}
 {\end{tabular}}
\newenvironment{explainformula}[1]
 {\begin{equation}#1\begin{formulaexplained}}
 {\end{formulaexplained}\end{equation}}
\newenvironment{explainformula*}[1]
 {\begin{equation*}#1\begin{formulaexplained}}
 {\end{formulaexplained}\end{equation*}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[3]
\begin{explainformula}{
  \Ren = \frac{vd}{\nu}
}
\Ren & Reynolds number (--)\\
v    & velocity of the fluid (\si{\milli\meter\per\second})\\
d    & characteristic linear dimension (\si{\milli\meter})\\
\nu  & kinematic viscosity (\si{\milli\meter\squared\per\second})
\end{explainformula}
\lipsum*[3]
\begin{explainformula*}{
  \Ren = \frac{vd}{\nu}
}
\Ren & Reynolds number (--)\\
v    & velocity of the fluid (\si{\milli\meter\per\second})\\
d    & characteristic linear dimension (\si{\milli\meter})\\
\nu  & kinematic viscosity (\si{\milli\meter\squared\per\second})
\end{explainformula*}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]