# How to combine/unite/merge two environments?

Tags: tables, equations, environments, environment-variables

I have two enviroments (equation and tabular), which should be located near to each other.

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[14pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX},Renderer=Basic}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={TeX,Historic}]{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\frenchspacing

%%% Tables.
\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow}
%

%%% Page
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=20mm, bottom=20mm, left=20mm, right=15mm}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,mathtools}

\begin{document}

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.

\begin{equation}
\overline{K_p} = \sqrt[n]{\prod K_\textup{chain}},
\end{equation}
%\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{llll}
        where & $\overline{K_p}$ & {---} & coefficient of growth; \\
        \addlinespace
        & $K_\textup{chain}$ & {---} & \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}chain coefficients of growth;\end{tabular} \\
        \addlinespace
        & $n$ & {---} & \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}number of chain coefficients.\end{tabular}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

But they are located like this
[image]

Sometimes between them stands the text "Lorem Ipsum".

I need that this 2 environments will located near to each other. So that there is no text between them.

Maybe exist is a container for combining these two environments? Or something else.

P.S. String:

```
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
```

I'm using for decrease a distance between environments.

Comment: Put them into a `minipage`. And *don't use `table` but only `tabular`*. A float floats if you use a float.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398457/typesetting-formula-beside-explanation-of-variables

Comment: "don't use table but only tabular", and     \begin{minipage}[h]{1\textwidth}
\begin{equation}
\overline{K_p} = \sqrt[n]{\prod K_\textup{chain}},
\end{equation}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
 where & $\overline{K_p}$ & {---} & coefficient of growth; \\
 \addlinespace
 & $K_\textup{chain}$ & {---} & \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}chain coefficients of growth;\end{tabular} \\
 \addlinespace
 & $n$ & {---} & \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}number of chain coefficients.\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}  Thank you. It helped.

Comment: You can answer your own question.  After a day or so you can accept your own answer and close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `gather`:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[14pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,mathtools}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\geometry{top=20mm, bottom=20mm, left=20mm, right=15mm}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\frenchspacing

\begin{document}
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy 
text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley 
of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
\begin{gather}
\overline{K_p} = \sqrt[n]{\prod K_\textup{chain}},
\\[\medskipamount]
\begin{tabular}{llll}
where & $\overline{K_p}$ & {---} & coefficient of growth; \\
\addlinespace
      & $K_\textup{chain}$ & {---} & chain coefficients of growth; \\
\addlinespace
      & $n$ & {---} & number of chain coefficients.
\end{tabular}
\notag
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

I reformatted your preamble and added `newtxmath` in order to get math symbols compatible with Times New Roman. Note that you don't need to specify `TeX` ligatures that are on by default and that the font has no `Historic` ligatures.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\begin{minipage}[h]{1\textwidth}
\begin{equation}
\overline{K_p} = \sqrt[n]{\prod K_\textup{chain}},
\end{equation}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
    where & $\overline{K_p}$ & {---} & coefficient of growth; \\
    \addlinespace
    & $K_\textup{chain}$ & {---} & \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}chain coefficients of growth;\end{tabular} \\
    \addlinespace
    & $n$ & {---} & \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}number of chain coefficients.\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
```

[image]